# Dimensional Data modeling for the Olist e-commerce cvs datasets

Tags: database, qliksense, dimensional-modeling

I am working on a case study of the Olist Brazilian e-commerce platform. The goal is to model a dimensional database, and from there answer some business questions with QlikSense's analysis and dashboarding.

CSV files have been extracted from this E-R model :
[Olist E-R database model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdYYt.png)

To answer business requirements, the granularity will be at order_items level, as each line will give measurable attributes (price, freight_value).

I am in the process of building the dimensional model as a Star Schema with one Fact table and several Dimension tables, but I am stuck with Orders and Orders_items datasets and do not know how to handle them.

- Do I need to consider Orders_items as a separate Dimension or do I need to put them into the a Fact_orders table?
- Is there any other approach I may consider?
  [Dimensional model construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iUJ1.jpg)

Comment: When you say Order_Items in your question, is this referring to Order_Item_ID or DIM_ORDER_ITEMS in your db model?

Comment: I can only give high-level advice, such as best practices and convention, with what I'm seeing. If you could provide a database relationship schema that shows all the fields and which entries are used as keys, I could more accurately assist you

Comment: Hi bananabrann. I am referring to the csv dataset files. One is labelled Orders and the other one is labelled Orders_items. Yes I am building the DWH Dim and Fact tables so I may send you a copy of the SQL file once done :-) If you need to have a look at the csv files of this case study they are available here : https://www.kaggle.com/olistbr/brazilian-ecommerce/download